# Regex para capturar dimensões de um produto com unidade de medida

Tags: python, regex

Tenho uma função em python para capturar as dimensões de um produto no formato LxCxA mas não consigo fazer funcionar para casos onde aparece a unidade de medida entre os valores, o regex é esse aqui:

```
def findDimensions(text):
    p = re.compile(r'(?P<l>\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*x\s*(?P<w>\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*x\s*(?P<h>\d+(\.\d+)?)')
    m = p.search(text)
    if (m):
        return m.group("l"), m.group("w"), m.group("h")
    return None
```

Ele funciona para os 2 casos abaixo:

23,6 x 34 x 17,1

14,5 x 55 x 22

Mas não funciona para este por exemplo:

14,5cmx55x22cm

Gostaria de fazer funcionar para situações em que apareçam quaisquer quantidades de espaços ou letras em cada grupo de valores separados pelo x. Tentei usar o \w*\W* mas não resolve para todos os casos, como este:

14,5 cmx55 cmx22 cm

Exemplo no regex101: https://regex101.com/r/bFywrT/3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aceito sugestões de expressão mais enxuta contato que atenda os exemplos mostrados

Comment: Primeiramente: Você quer só saber como faz para regex funcionar ou você aceitaria outra sugestão (tipo, sem regex) para seu problema? Afinal, você não informou para o que necessita disso. Talvez pudesse ser resolvido com a resposta já dada, por outro lado, acho que não ficou claro se você precisa de ter as unidades de medida junto aos números.

Comment: Wallace, gostaria de resolver apenas ajustando a expressão para se adequar ao caso que falei. Mesmo que tenha que ser um regex completamente novo. Atendendo ao último caso mencionado.

Comment: A questão não é ser um regex novo, a questão é: "Você aceita uma solução sem regex?"

Comment: Não. Agradeço mas quero resolver apenas com o ajuste na expressão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Regex

Com a seguinte expressão regular: `([\d,]+)[\s\D]*` é possível capturar cada valor dado.

E com a expressão regular `([\d,]+)[\s\D]*([\d,]+)[\s\D]*([\d,]+)[\s\D]*` e a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7TMVAZ/1), é possível obter as dimensões.

## Explicação

A seguinte expressão regular pode ser repetida três vezes para obter as dimensões em cada grupo de captura.

- #### 1° Grupo de Captura `([\d,]+)`

  - Corresponde a um item presente na lista entre `[]`
  - `\d`: Corresponde a um dígito entre 0 e 9
  - `,`: Corresponde literalmente ao caractere vírgula
  - `+`: Quantificador que corresponde de uma a ilimitadas vezes, quantas vezes for possível (greedy).
- Seguido de `[\s\D]*`

  - Corresponde a um item presente na lista entre `[]`
  - `\s`: Corresponde a qualquer espaço em branco (igual a [\r\n\t\f\v])
  - `\D`: Corresponde a qualquer caractere que não é um dígito (diferente de [^0-9])
  - `*`:  Quantificador que corresponde de zero a ilimitadas vezes, quantas vezes for possível (greedy).

## Código Dimensões

Segue um código de exemplo de implementação em Python:

```
import re

regex_pattern= re.compile(r"([\d,]+)[\s\D]*([\d,]+)[\s\D]*([\d,]+)[\s\D]*")
regex_string="""23,6 x 34 x 17,1
14,5 x 55 x 22
14,5cm x 55 x 22cm
14,5cmx55x22cm
14,5 cmx55 cmx22 cm"""

matches = re.finditer(regex_pattern, regex_string)

for submatch in matches:
    if submatch:
        print("L: " + submatch.group(1) + " C: " + submatch.group(2) + " A: " + submatch.group(3))
```

#### Resultado:

```
L: 23,6 C: 34 A: 17,1
L: 14,5 C: 55 A: 22
L: 14,5 C: 55 A: 22
L: 14,5 C: 55 A: 22
L: 14,5 C: 55 A: 22
```

## Código Cada Valor

Ou o exemplo para cada valor da string:

```
import re

regex_pattern= re.compile(r"([\d,]+)[\s\D]*")
regex_string="""23,6 x 34 x 17,1
14,5 x 55 x 22
14,5cm x 55 x 22cm
14,5cmx55x22cm
14,5 cmx55 cmx22 cm"""

matches = re.finditer(regex_pattern, regex_string)

for submatch in matches:
    if submatch:
        print(submatch.groups())
```

#### Resultado

```
('23,6',)
('34',)
('17,1',)
('14,5',)
('55',)
('22',)
('14,5',)
('55',)
('22',)
('14,5',)
('55',)
('22',)
('14,5',)
('55',)
('22',)
```

Comment: Putz solução fantástica Daniel, bem mais enxuta e legível. E ainda funciona para situações futuras onde pode aparecer outros caracteres no meio.

Comment: Apliquei para o caso onde tenho LxA aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, só tirei a última repetição da expressão que você comentou. Não era minha intenção inicial mas já foram 2 coelhos em uma só cajadada. ^^

Comment: Para facilitar para outros leitores, já que a pergunta tem a tag Python seria legal colocar o exemplo completo - quais funções são chamadas, qual é a saida, etc...

Comment: @jsbueno vou adicionar lá para quem desejar usar. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: @rodrigorf o motivo de eu não ter usado `[\d,]+` como na do daniel é que se tiver algum valor no input errado, como por exemplo `1,00 ,00` ele vai casar também, o que pode ser problema, por isso procurei ser mais *estrito* ao escrever a regex

Answer (score 4):

**"Simplesmente simplifique"** usando `(\s+)?` para os espaços **serem opcionais**, a regex não tem como ficar muito simples, mas no seu caso dá para simplificar um pouco, assim:

```
(\d+(,\d+)?)(\s+)?(cm)?(\s+)?x(\s+)?(\d+(,\d+)?)(\s+)?(cm)?(\s+)?x(\s+)?(\d+(,\d+)?)(\s+)?(cm)?
```

Exemplo online no RegEr: https://regexr.com/3rpmr

---

### Explicando a regex

A primeira parte da regex seria isto:

```
(\d+(,\d+)?)(\s+)?(cm)?
```

- O `(,\d+)?` busca opcionalmente o numero pós virgula
- O `(\s+)?` busca um ou mais espaços opicionalmente
- O `(cm)?` busca a medida opicionalmente

Pronto, após isso é só usar um `x` entre repetindo a expressão, claro que dá para fazer de outras formas, mas o resultado seria quase o mesmo, dessa forma é repetitiva mas mais compreensiva

Se o objetivo é buscar uma entrada por vez então aplicar o `\b` no começo e fim já deve resolver também, por exemplo:

```
\b(\d+(,\d+)?)(\s+)?(cm)?(\s+)?x(\s+)?(\d+(,\d+)?)(\s+)?(cm)?(\s+)?x(\s+)?(\d+(,\d+)?)(\s+)?(cm)?\b
```

---

### Multiplos valores

Agora se a entrada tiver vários valores assim então faça desta forma:

```
import re

expressao = r'(\d+(,\d+)?)(\s+)?(cm)?(\s+)?x(\s+)?(\d+(,\d+)?)(\s+)?(cm)?(\s+)?x(\s+)?(\d+(,\d+)?)(\s+)?(cm)?'

entrada = '''
23,6 x 34 x 17,1
14,5 x 55 x 22
14,5cm x 55 x 22cm
14,5cmx55x22cm
14,5 cmx55 cmx22 cm
''';

resultados = re.finditer(expressao, entrada)

for resultado in resultados:
    valores = resultado.groups()
    print("Primeiro:", valores[0])
    print("Segundo:", valores[6])
    print("Terceiro:", valores[12])
    print("\n")
```

Note que o group na regex esta de 6 em 6 para pegar cada numero entre os `X`, ou seja, cada group retorna algo como:

> ```
> ('23,6', ',6', ' ', None, None, ' ', '34', None, ' ', None, None, ' ', '17,1', ',1', '\n', None)
> ('14,5', ',5', ' ', None, None, ' ', '55', None, ' ', None, None, ' ', '22', None, '\n', None)
> ('14,5', ',5', None, 'cm', ' ', ' ', '55', None, ' ', None, None, ' ', '22', None, None, 'cm')
> ('14,5', ',5', None, 'cm', None, None, '55', None, None, None, None, None, '22', None, None, 'cm')
> ('14,5', ',5', ' ', 'cm', None, None, '55', None, ' ', 'cm', None, None, '22', None, ' ', 'cm')
> ```

Então por isso irá usar somente os `valores[0]`, `valores[6]` e `valores[12]`, exemplo no repl.it: https://repl.it/@inphinit/regex-python-extract

---

### Usando valores para operações matematicas

Note que `,` não faz o numero ser considerado um "numero" para o Python, então se vai fazer uma operação matematica converta para `float`, assim:

```
float('1000,00001'.replace(',', ','))
```

Deve ser algo assim:

```
for resultado in resultados:
    valores = resultado.groups()

    primeiro = float(valores[0].replace(',', '.'))
    segundo = float(valores[6].replace(',', '.'))
    terceiro = float(valores[12].replace(',', '.'))

    print("Primeiro:", primeiro)
    print("Segundo:", segundo)
    print("Terceiro:", terceiro)
    print("Resultado:", primeiro * segundo * terceiro)
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Os número que vou extrair são justamente esses (valores[0], valores[6] e valores[12]). É o que preciso. No caso que tenho resolve para 'cm' mas se a unidade for diferente teria como subsituir por qualquer cominação de caracteres?

Comment: @rodrigorf adicionei exemplo de como usar em operações matemáticas e adicionei os exemplos online, tanto do regex no https://regexr.com/3rpmr quanto do script python no https://repl.it/@inphinit/regex-python-extract

Answer (score 3):

Você consegue fazer isso sem uso de regex. Basta "limpar" a string removendo espaços e o "cm", depois quebrar em array pelo "x":

```
str = "4,5cmx55x22cm";
str = str.replace('cm', '').replace(' ', '')
str = str.split('x')
print str # ['4,5', '55', '22']
```

**[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/0zwvFS)**

Convertendo a string em array você tem os valores separados por índices, e poderá usá-los como quiser. Se quiser que o resultado seja no formato `Lcm x Acm x Ccm`, você pode converter a array em string adicionando o `cm x`:

```
str = "4,5cm x55x 22cm ";
str = str.replace('cm', '').replace(' ', '').split('x')
str = 'cm x '.join(str)+"cm"
print str # retorna 4,5cm x 55cm x 22cm
```

### Regex

```
(?P<l>[\d|,]+)(.*?)x(.*?)(?P<w>[\d|,]+)(.*?)x(.*?)(?P<h>[\d|,]+)(.*?)
```

O `(.*?)` verifica se há ou não qualquer caractere entre o número e o `x`. O `[\d|,]+` captura números ou vírgula. Nomeando os grupos você consegue pegar o valor pelo nome.

**Código:**

```
import re
str = "4,5cm x55x 22cm ";
regex = "(?P<l>[\d|,]+)(.*?)x(.*?)(?P<w>[\d|,]+)(.*?)x(.*?)(?P<h>[\d|,]+)(.*?)"
resultado = re.match(regex, str)
print resultado.groupdict()['l'] # retorna 4,5
print resultado.groupdict()['w'] # retorna 55
print resultado.groupdict()['h'] # retorna 22
```

**[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/OntRTP)**

Comment: apesar de estar explicito na pergunta, eu também prefiro não usar regex onde não precisa de regex.  :-)

Comment: nesse caso, a performance é negligível, e se você for comparar com os replaces em sério, etc.;. a regex deve ser até mais performática. O maior problema aí é legibilidade e manutenção mesmo

Comment: @jsbueno Entendi. Realmente fica bem mais legível. Mas a resposta é uma sugestão apenas. :)

Comment: Agradeço pelos comentários. Estou usando regex porque já possuo vários tratamentos com expressão regular para capturar informações de textos, acredito que em termos de performance não deve ter muita diferença enre uma e outra mas como coloquei na descrição quero ajustar para atender ao último caso(com o cm) via regex.

Comment: @rodrigorf Blz! Estou tentando aqui montar uma regex.

Comment: Beleza @dvd, agradeço desde já o esforço.

Comment: @rodrigorf mas vc quer pegar só os números?

Comment: @dvd isso. Só os números

Comment: @rodrigorf Coloquei uma regex um pouco mais simples.

Answer (score 3):

Regex realmente pode extrair os três valores "numa única linha de código", mas perceba que isso é uma ilusão - você está num ponto em que  `(?P<l>\d+(\,\d+)?)\s*x\s*(?P<w>\d+(\,\d+)?)\s*x\s*(?P<h>\d+(\,\d+)?)` está simples demais e tem que ser _ainda_mais_ complicado - e mesmo alguém que pratique regexes todos os dias, tem que ler isso com muito mais calma do que alguém lendo 4 ou 5 linhas de código Python, que separa os valores em uma etapa em cada linha.

Mas, como você pergunta explicitamente por regex, vejamos:

O mais simples, em vez de repetir a lógica da regex 3 vezes, é usar o método "findall" das regexes em Python - eles já podem extrair todos os números - 
assim, podemos usar:

```
In [19]: a = ["23,6 x 34 x 17,1", "14,5 x 55x 22", "14,5cmx55x22cm", "23  cmx 12.1cmx 14,36"]
In [20]: [re.findall(r"([\d,.]+)\s*?(?:cm)?", text) for text in a]
Out[20]: 
[['23,6', '34', '17,1'],
 ['14,5', '55', '22'],
 ['14,5', '55', '22'],
 ['23', '12.1', '14,36']]
```

O que permite que o "cm" seja opcional é a parte (?:cm)  - embora nessa expressão nem precise disso, ela simplesmetne vai extrair todos os números que tenham ou nã marcadores "," ou "." como decimais.

É uma expressão bem mais simples que a sua original - e com o `findall` recupera 3 números, se os houver - um "if" em Python pode ignorar o dado, ou gerar uma exceção se você não tiver os 3 números.

Tem se que ter em mente que expressões regulares são literalmente uma linguagem à parte da linguagem do programa - nesse caso, a expressão ficou bastante simples e razoável de ser mantida, embora ignore muitos *corner-cases* - em Python, você poderia obter o mesmo resultado com:

```
In [21]: a = ["23,6 x 34 x 17,1", "14,5 x 55x 22", "14,5cmx55x22cm", "23  cmx 12.1cmx 14,36"]


In [22]: [[dimensao.replace("cm", "").strip()  for dimensao in dado.split("x")]   for dado in a]
Out[22]: 
[['23,6', '34', '17,1'],
 ['14,5', '55', '22'],
 ['14,5', '55', '22'],
 ['23', '12.1', '14,36']]
```

(Assim como no caso do exemplo com regexp, a *comprehension* mais externa só faz percorrer todos os exemplos de dimensões em "a") - Ou seja, nesse caso, você extrai os números usando uma *list comprehension* e nem precisa de mais de uma linha de código.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a seguinte expressão:

```
[^0-9,.]
```

Que é capaz de substituir tudo que for diferente de digitos numéricos, pontos e vírgulas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em uma função:

```
import re

def findDimensions(text):
    s = re.sub('[^0-9,.]', ' ', text ).replace(',', '.').split()
    return tuple([ float(n) for n in s])
```

Testando:

```
import re

def findDimensions(text):
    s = re.sub('[^0-9,.]', ' ', text ).replace(',', '.').split()
    return tuple([ float(n) for n in s])

print(findDimensions("14,5 x 55 x 22,0"))
print(findDimensions("14,5 x 55cm x 22"))
print(findDimensions("14,5cm x 55 x 22cm"))
print(findDimensions("14,5cmx55x22cm"))
print(findDimensions("14,5 cmx55 cmx22 cm"))
print(findDimensions("14,5 cm x 55.0 x 22.0 cm"))
```

Saída:

```
(14.5, 55.0, 22.0)
(14.5, 55.0, 22.0)
(14.5, 55.0, 22.0)
(14.5, 55.0, 22.0)
(14.5, 55.0, 22.0)
(14.5, 55.0, 22.0)
```

Veja a expressão regular funcionando no [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bFywrT/5).

Veja o código de teste rodando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/lERoFT)